# How to Use Build Targets In Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, build-target

I'm quite familiar with the workings of Xcode, except for Build Targets.
I need to add a special Build Target for handling notifications, containing a class used to process the notifications (call this `Class B`). Inside of this target, I access a method from a class located in the main build target (call this `Class A`)

The issue is that I cannot add the `Class A` 's method to be a part of `Class B`'s, since doing so causes tons of `Cannot find Type in Scope` errors from ever classes referenced inside of `Class A` that has not been added to the build target .

How can I avoid these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can select class A for both the target, and then create a extension for the methods which are only related to particular target,  let's say you have 2 targets X and Y and you have 2 class A and B, class A belongs target X and class B blongs to target Y then if you want some of the factions of class A in in target Y then you need to select class A for both the target from side panel and then can access that in both the target and if there are some methods which you only want for target X and the you can create extension of class A(individual file) and assign that to respective target only(i.e target X)

Comment: But the only issue is that with the extension of class A, the compiler throws an error because it doesn't recognize class A.